# How to deal with a non-significant threshold value in ordinal regression in SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss, ordered-logit

I am running an ordinal regression in SPSS. I have independent variables on nominal and ordinal scales. My dependent variable is ordinal, indicating a level of action, coded 0, 1, 2. Unfortunately, I currently don’t know how to deal with the non-significance of a threshold level for my dependent variable indicated by SPSS in the parameter estimates table.

The SPSS output of the parameter estimates looks like this:

Threshold       Level of action = 0     Estimate =  .6 Sig. = .143

Threshold Level of action = 1   Estimate = 2.2  Sig. = .000

Independent variables …

I read that “*non-significance of a threshold suggests that the cutting point is not truly different and therefore some levels of the dependent variable need to be combined*” (Garson, G. D. (2012). Ordinal Regression. Asheboro, NC: Statistical Associates Publishers).
I have not come across such a statement before. Also some ordinal regressions I had a look at did not mention an issue regarding a non-significant threshold and interpreted the output nonetheless.

So now I am wondering how severe that issue is. If I stick with ordinal regression, how would this non-significant threshold impact my results (given all other assumption are met)? Would they still be valid? Or does this mean that I definitely have to combine the outcome categories 0 and 1, which basically would mean I need to run binary logistic regression instead of ordinal regression?

Comment: I would think it is best to ignore this.  But it would help to have an exact definition of "threshold".  Is it just an intercept estimate?  This is highly nonstandard nomenclature.

Comment: @Frank, Yes, in SPSS "threshold" is the intercept for each logit. Lena, thresholds are used in computation of predicted probabilities but they usually are of minor importance in interpreting a regression results.

Comment: Then the statement by Garson is not correct.  It is not a good idea to look at the significance of the intercepts.  The intercepts are driven by the marginal distribution of $Y$ and are manipulated by the centering of $X$ so no interesting hypotheses come from them alone.  And looking at them does not provide information about pooling some of the $Y$ values.

Comment: @Frank, what can you say about the idea to combine ordinal categories which thresholds' CI overlap?

Comment: Please read my previous comment again.  The values of the intercepts have absolutely nothing to do with whether categories should be collapsed.  The intercept just reflects the frequencies of categories.  By your logic you would collapse two adjacent categories having only one observation each even though they are meaningfully different $Y$ values.  What if you had a sample size of 500 and had no ties in $Y$ so that all $Y$s had a frequency of one?  You still would not collapse any levels.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers were very helpful. I'll leave the categories uncombined then.